# What is property "displayName" in React? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get the following error and nothing in the error log helps me locate or detect where my mistake is coming from.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null
    at getDisplayName (VM12922 backend.js:9159)
    at getDataFiber (VM12922 backend.js:9888)
    at enqueueMount (VM12922 backend.js:10158)
    at mountFiber (VM12922 backend.js:10246)
    at VM12922 backend.js:10306
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.walkTree (VM12922 backend.js:10304)
    at VM12922 backend.js:8534
    at <anonymous>:52:32
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (<anonymous>:51:66)
    at setupBackend (VM12922 backend.js:8621)
    at module.exports (VM12922 backend.js:8567)
    at Agent.<anonymous> (VM12922 backend.js:116)
    at Agent.g (VM12922 backend.js:981)
    at Agent.EventEmitter.emit (VM12922 backend.js:894)
    at VM12922 backend.js:302
    at VM12922 backend.js:7619
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at VM12922 backend.js:7618
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Bridge._handleMessage (VM12922 backend.js:7611)
    at listener (VM12922 backend.js:92)
```

Because of this error, React devtools wont load to possibly pinpoint the error.

What is this and where do I start. I only have two main components, the code compiles and renders. What does "displayName" refer to?

Comment: The display name is the human readable name of the component. If not explicitly set it's usually the class or function name. However, `displayName` isn't your problem. The problem is that you are passing `null` instead of a component to somewhere where React expects a component. My guess is that you are importing components incorrectly or something like that. Impossible to help without seeing your actual code though.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lxo3z4lyrq, no styling

Comment: I noticed I forgot the 's' on Albums, in Albums component. I added it, but the error still persists.

Comment: Do you get the error if you remove all external dependencies (besides React of course)?

Comment: yes, I removed all of fontawesome and axios

Comment: Another thing I can't figure out is why, when you hover over the search bar, "search for an artist" still comes up. I got rid of that a long time ago and there is nowhere in the code that this appears.

Comment: @KevinT. Restart chrome worked for me. It updated react-devtools :)